# LiveCD with NVidia binary drivers

Tags: nvidia, live-cd

I'd like to modify the LiveCD to boot with the NVidia binary drivers. Any ideas of how that might be done? I've tried several approaches, even a manual installation of the NVidia installer in a chrooted filesystem, but no success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Live USB instead of a Live CD.  Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator application will let you do this, and it allows you to save data as well as a persistent storage medium.  You will need to load the ISO onto the USB and run it, install the NVidia drivers and you can then reuse it.  It effectively becomes a portalable Ubuntu.

Here are some instructions on the Ubuntu Help website:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: Thanks! And I could do that and then recreate the CD ISO from the altered USB filesystem. Anything I should watch for while moving back to the CD?

Comment: Sorry, I've never gone from USB to ISO, so I can't tell if the new ISO that you create will work.  CDs/DVDs use ISOLINUX, while USBs use SYSLINUX.  I will speculate and say that even if you take the USB's contents and simply image it, it won't work. You'll probably need to stick to the USB drive.